# vandermonde matrix Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to coding in the Python3 language. I am trying to write a code that takes the data provided below and computes the Vandermonde matrix with out using numpy any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
data:
x= [0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00]
y = [1.102,1.099,1.017,1.111,1.117,1.152,1.265,1.380,1.575,1.857]
degree n = 4
```